# Using moq with AnyAsync() extension to GetAll()

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I'm writing a unit test that requires me to mock a respository call with the GetAll() method shown below -

```
var name = await _scheduleRepository
                .GetAll()
                .AnyAsync(s => s.Id != schedule.Id && s.Name == schedule.Name);
```

When I tried writing the Moq call for the GetAll() method alone, the main application code throws a NullReferenceException indicating that the mocked data is not getting picked up.

```
_scheduleRespository.Setup(repository => repository.GetAll()).Returns(testList.AsQueryable());
```

I've looked into mocking the Async call itself -

```
_scheduleRespository.Setup(r => r.GetAll().AnyAsync(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<ProcessSchedule, bool>>>()))
                    .Callback<Expression<Func<ProcessSchedule, bool>>>(
                        expression =>
                        {
                            var func = expression.Compile();
                            foo = func(new ProcessSchedule() { Name = "FAKE_NAME", Id = 3 });
                        })
                    .Returns(() => Task.FromResult(foo));
```

but this returns a different error shown below -

```
Message: System.NotSupportedException : Invalid setup on an extension method: r => r.GetAll().AnyAsync<ProcessSchedule>(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<ProcessSchedule, bool>>>())
```

Is it even possible to Moq that method or will I have to consider rewriting my main application code?

Comment: Have you tried `_scheduleRespository.Setup(r => r.GetAll().AnyAsync(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<ProcessSchedule, bool>>>())).ReturnsAsync(testList.AsQueryable())` ?

Comment: This returns the following error : 
`'ISetup<IRepository<ProcessSchedule>, Task<bool>>' does not contain a definition for 'ReturnsAsync' and the best extension method overload 'SequenceExtensions.ReturnsAsync<IQueryable<ProcessSchedule>>(ISetupSequentialResult<Task<IQueryable<ProcessSchedule>>>, IQueryable<ProcessSchedule>)' requires a receiver of type 'ISetupSequentialResult<Task<IQueryable<ProcessSchedule>>>'`

Comment: `AnyAsync` is an extension method. Moq does not mock extension methods. `AnyAsync` also expects a an `IQueryable` source that also implements `IDbAsyncQueryProvider`

Comment: @Nkosi does this mean I would have to rewrite my main application code to be able to use Moq or is there a workaround?